# How to install hwloc-dev package on Docker alpine container

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

The hwloc-dev package missing on the Docker Alpine Linux container.

```
 # apk add hwloc-dev hwloc-tools
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  hwloc-dev (missing):
    required by: world[hwloc-dev]
  hwloc-tools (missing):
```

Answer (score 2):

As indicated by the [package explorer](https://alpine.pkgs.org/edge/alpine-community-x86_64/hwloc-dev-2.2.0-r0.apk.html), this package is in the alpine edge community repository.

You need to add it to your `/etc/apk/repositories`:

```sh
echo 'https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community' >> /etc/apk/repositories
```